# Spring OAuth testing /oauth/check_token through postman

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to authorize my api's of resource server from authorization server. 
My resource server contains following configuration. 
Now I want to test the check_token end point but it always returns unauthorized error. 
I am passing authorization object in request header(as you can see in below screenshot.)

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.resourceId("adminProfile").authenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean())
                .tokenExtractor(new CustomTokenExtractor());
    }
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public RemoteTokenServices tokenService() {
        RemoteTokenServices tokenService = new RemoteTokenServices();
        tokenService.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl(
                "http://localhost:8080/oauth/check_token");
        tokenService.setClientId("clientId");
        tokenService.setClientSecret("secretId");
        return tokenService;
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = new OAuth2AuthenticationManager();
        authenticationManager.setTokenServices(tokenService());
        return authenticationManager;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I know it is old. What is your Authorization Server configuration? Above code only shows resource server config. /oauth/check_token endpoint needs to be accessible on Auth Server side.

Comment: Yes my authorization server implementation is old and the issue was that check-token was not enabled.
<oauth:authorization-server check-token-enabled="true"

Answer (score 0):

after reading documentation I found that check-token-enabled flag needs to be added in configuration.

```
<oauth:authorization-server check-token-enabled="true" client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices" user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler" >
        <oauth:authorization-code/>
        <oauth:implicit />
        <oauth:refresh-token />
        <oauth:client-credentials/>
        <oauth:password />
    </oauth:authorization-server>
```